# Visa requirement during a layover at a German airport for Colombian citizens flying to Turkey

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, germany, colombian-citizens

My Mother would like to visit me in Istanbul, her flight is Miami-Frankfurt-Istanbul. Due to her Colombian nationality, does she requires a transit visa?

Comment: How long will the layover be?

Answer (score 2):

Colombian nationals do not need a visa to transit at a Schengen airport, including Frankfurt, provided they don't need to leave the international arrival lounge. See [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area)

There are also plans to allow Colombian nationals to *enter* the Schengen area without visa but I am not entirely sure of the current status of all this. [The relevant legal text](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/LKD/?uri=CELEX:32001R0539) has been amended but the EU [also needs to conclude a visa waiver agreement with Colombia](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_STATEMENT-14-19_es.htm) (a whole process in itself) and [the official website still lists Colombia as a country whose citizens need a visa](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/index_en.htm).

Comment: The German embassy in Bogota states in their information material that the visa exemption for Colombian citizens most likely wont be in effect until next year (2015).